# How do I remove a 'pmset' auto-wakeup command for my Mac?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, imac

`pmset repeat shutdown MTWRFSU 06:00:00 wakeorpoweron MTWRFSU 06:05:00`

Such command in the terminal works perfectly fine on my Mac.
But I'm just curious if I don't need it one day, how am I supposed to remove or undo it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple. Execute `pmset repeat cancel`.