# pmset repeat cancel does not remove scheduled events

Tags: macos, command-line, sleep-wake, pmset

After some time searching, I found this answer:
[How do I remove 'pmset' auto-wakeup command for my Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/457025/432220)

But the solution is not working for me. I originally had my laptop scheduled to restart at midnight, every day. That schedule is now missing but has been replaced by two wake events:

```
user@COMPUTER / % pmset -g sched          
Scheduled power events:
 [0]  wake at 12/28/2023 11:51:49 by 'com.apple.alarm.user-visible-com.apple.calaccessd.travelEngine.periodicRefreshTimer'
 [1]  wake at 12/29/2023 04:04:04 by 'com.apple.alarm.user-visible-com.apple.acmd.alarm'
user@COMPUTER / %
```

No amount of running `pmset repeat cancel` removes them. Does anyone have any insight on this?

UPDATE: Well, I just got back to this and the events are no longer even showing up. I've saved the question so if they come back up, I'll walk through the potential solutions provided.

UPDATE 1: The problem suddenly resolved itself. I am not sure what I did differently that might have caused it to resolved. But It's over now. Thank you for all the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scheduled entries are *one off* events, scheduled by parts of macOS. They are not *repeating*.

### Cancelling with `pmset`

To cancel one off events, use the [`pmset`](https://www.dssw.co.uk/reference/pmset/) command with these options:

```
sudo pmset schedule cancelall
```

A `… schedule cancel` form exists to provide more control over which entries to cancel:

```
sudo pmset schedule [cancel | cancelall] type date+time [owner]
```

### Apple Owned

Note that these entries are owned by `com.apple.*` and are not expected to be cancelled by the user, so you may experience unexpected behaviour.

The entries in your question are created by macOS and are part of the running of the operating system. Both bundle identifiers suggest the owning process are system daemons: `acmd`, [`calaccessd`](https://keith.github.io/xcode-man-pages/calaccessd.8.html). These are normal and expected entries.

Comment: I suspect the additional information here with the syntax is where I went wrong. Thanks for this. I'm selecting your solution for now because of that.

Comment: On the unexpected behavior, they shouldn't be there. I created a scheduled restart that has now disappeared and is replaced by the two noted instances that I did not create. I have scanned for viruses and what not, but did not think to check the scheduled operations until I noticed my machine was restarting at the wrong time. So here I am. They should not exist and the one that should no longer comes up. It gets even weirder when considering that the items shown in the original post are now showing up even though did not earlier today. I just cleared them and waiting to see what happens

Answer (score 4):

The man page suggests using sudo, as “pmset must be run as root in order to modify any settings.”

```
sudo pmset repeat cancel
```

Source: https://ss64.com/osx/pmset.html

Comment: Yes sir, apologies, I did try it that way in my original attempts. Graham's answer included some more information that I didn't think of and did not try. I failed to slow down and read through the man page. That was my bad. Thank you for helping out, it's appreciated