# Shutdown error that cannot be pinned down

Tags: macos, command-line, sleep-wake, power-management, pmset

Here is the issue in a nutshell: My machine has taken to giving me an error dialog that begins with the following on every restart or shutdown and restart, manual or otherwise:

> You shut down your computer because of
> a problem. If you want to open the applications that were
> open when
> you shut down, click Open.

The research I've done can be found [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/467835/pmset-repeat-cancel-does-not-remove-scheduled-events/467855#467855)

I figured it was related to the automated wake up operations that keep getting made but, after digging around more, it apparently doesn't.

I did find some information on the machine potentially being stuck in a kernel panic mode, but haven't been able to really pin down a potential fix. Any help here would be appreciated

Comment: It's a bit difficult to follow when details are spread across several posts. Can you edit this question here to just focus on the actual problem which you need help with right now? From what I understand, you just want to know where these two events are coming from?

Comment: Also, the answer you link to already explains that com.apple events are outside of the control of the user.

Comment: Yeah I absolutely can, and you're nearly spot on

Comment: That part I understand and I failed to clarify. I'll tweak the question to clarify here

Comment: @nohillside I went ahead and updated it to clarify in what I believe is the way you described. I am starting to think I may need to split this into two questions though. If you have anymore input, it would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. The question still seems to ask two different questions though, so it may be worth splitting it. Also, as mentioned, the answer to the second question is in the answer you link to: "The entries in your question are created by macOS and are part of the running of the operating system. Both bundle identifiers suggest the owning process are system daemons: acmd, calaccessd. These are normal and expected entries."

Comment: Apparently I didn't read thoroughly enough. I'll cut that part off and deal with it later. Thank you for the guidance, it's greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

## Isolating the Cause

You mention your Mac reports a problem after *every* restart:

> My machine has taken to giving me an error dialog that begins with the
> following on every restart or shutdown and restart, manual or
> otherwise:

Does your Mac continue to report the problem after [starting up in safe mode](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mh21245/mac) and manually restarting?

> #### Safe mode
>
> Safe mode may help you resolve or isolate problems that you’re having with your Mac.
>
> When you start up in safe mode, your Mac prevents some software, such as startup items, from loading, and it performs a check of your startup disk. Your Mac may take longer to start up because of the check.

If the problem occurs after safe mode, it may be hardware related. Try restarting from safe mode again with only a wired keyboard and mouse connected to your Mac.

If the problem does not appear after a safe mode restart, then software is likely to be the cause.

### Logs

Without more details, it will be difficult to answer this question fully.

Check the contents of `/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports` for possible logged problems. [Others report](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253623169?=undefined&previousThread=252385119021&sortBy=best) that removing these files can also fix the problem.